# How do I display Conway's game of life in python.

Tags: python

I recently made Conway's game of life in my comp sci class. Our class ended a few days ago and I wanted to make my game look a little better. currently this is what I have which prints boards with 0s and Xs and prints a new board each iteration which is either too slow in the python IDLE and too fast in command prompt to even see whats happening. How can I display it on a board which reuses the same board to print each iteration instead of creating a new board for each iteration. Any Suggestions on the code itself is appreciated.

```
def main():

    rows = input("Please enter the number of rows: ")   # asks the user for number of rows

    try :
        rows = int(rows)         # checks for a valid input
    except ValueError:
        rows = validChoice(rows)


    columns = input("Please enter the number of columns: ")    # asks the user for number of columns

    try :
        columns = int(columns)      # checks for valid column input
    except ValueError:
        columns = validChoice(columns)

    print ("")


    board = (makeBoard(rows, columns))   # calls makeboard function and saves in board variable as list

    print ("Indexing starts at 0 ")

    print ("")

    getMove = move(board, rows, columns)  # asks the user for which cells to turn on initially

    print ("")

    while getMove != "q" :    # while the user hasn't selected it loops through for the user to turn on multiple cells

        getMove = move(board, rows, columns)

        print ("")


    # Asks for the number of iterations to run
    iterations = input("How many iterations should I run? ")
    try:
        iterations = int(iterations)  # Asks for a valid iterations input if needed.
    except ValueError:
        iterations = validChoice(iterations)

    print ("")

    print ("Starting Board: ")

    print ("")

    printBoard(board) #Prints the starting board

    print ("")

    iteration = 1 # iteration starts at 1

    while iterations > 0 :      # Uses while loop to run through the iterations

        print ("Iteration", iteration, ":")

        print ("")

        iteration = iteration + 1 # adds iteration everytime

        board = nextIteration(board)  # runs board through iteration to see which cells will live and which will die

        board = fixBoard(board)  # corrects the board up to 0s and 1s     

        printBoard(board)  # prints board

        print ("")

        iterations = iterations - 1  # subtracts 1 iteration each time the program runs through each iteration

# turns 2 into a 0 because those cells died
# turns 3 into a 1 because those cells became alive
# returns boad with just 0s and 1s
def fixBoard(board):

    for i in range(len(board)):   # Uses for loop to go through each list inside list

        for x in range(len(board[0])): # Uses for loop to go through each index inside the list

            if board[i][x] == 2:
                board[i][x] = 0
            if board[i][x] == 3:
                board[i][x] = 1
    return (board)

# This function runs the game through each iteration
# Converts cells that will become alive next round to 3
# Converts cells that will become dead next round to 2
# Only checks specific cells for for cells around the edge of the board
# Uses nested for loops to go through each index
# Uses nested if  statements to check which cells around it are alive
# Input board with 0s and 1s returns board with 0s 1s 2s and 3s
def nextIteration(board):

    rose = len(board)
    cols = len(board[0])

    for x in range(rose):

        for i in range(cols):

            counter = 0

            if (x == 0) and (i == 0):
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i]==1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (x == 0) and (0 < i < (len(board[0])-1)):
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x][i] == 1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                    elif (counter > 3):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (x == 0) and (i == (len(board[0])-1)):

                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i]==1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (0 < x < (len(board)-1)) and (i == 0):

                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i] == 1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                    elif (counter > 3):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (0 < x < (len(board)-1)) and (0 < i < (len(board[0])-1)):

                if (board[x-1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x-1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x+1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter +1
                if (board[x][i] == 1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                    elif (counter > 3):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (0 < x < (len(board)-1)) and (i == (len(board[0])-1)):
                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x+1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x+1][i] == 1) or (board[x+1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i] == 1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                    elif (counter > 3):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (x == (len(board)-1)) and (i == 0):

                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i]==1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if ( x == (len(board)-1)) and ( i == (len(board[0])-1)):

                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i]==1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3

            if (x == (len(board)-1)) and (0 < i < (len(board[0])-1)):
                if (board[x][i-1] == 1) or (board[x][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i-1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i-1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i] == 1) or (board[x-1][i] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x-1][i+1] == 1) or (board[x-1][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i+1] == 1) or (board[x][i+1] ==2):
                    counter = counter + 1
                if (board[x][i] == 1):
                    if (counter == 2) or (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = board[x][i]
                    elif (counter < 2):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                    elif (counter > 3):
                        board[x][i] = 2
                if (board[x][i] == 0):
                    if (counter == 3):
                        board[x][i] = 3
    return (board)

# Asks the user for while cells they want to turn on
# Input board return Board
# Returns q if user doesn't want to turn on any more cells 
def move(board, rows, columns):

    #Asks for the row
    row = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on or q to exit: ")

    if row == "q" :
        return ("q")    # Checks for a valid choice of input by the user 
    else:
        try :
            row = int(row)
        except ValueError:
            row = validChoice(row)
        while row >= rows :
            row = validChoice(row)
    #Asks for the column
    col = input("Please enter a column for that cell: ")

    try :
        col = int(col)
    except ValueError:    # Checks for valid input
        col = validChoice(col)
    while col >= columns:
        col = validChoice(col)

    board[row][col] = 1

    return (board)

# Takes the board and prints it out to the user
# Leaves 0s and 0s and 1s to Xs
def printBoard(board):

    for i in range(len(board)): # uses for loop to go through each index

        for x in range(len(board[0])):

            if (board[i][x]) == 0:
                print (0, end="")
            elif (board[i][x]) == 1:
                print ('X', end="")
        print ("")

# Makes the board by using append method and lists    
def makeBoard(rows, columns):

    list2 = []  # this is the main list
    column = columns

    while rows > 0:
        list1 = []   # this is each list that will be inside the list

        while column > 0:
            list1.append(0)
            column = column - 1

        list2.append(list1)
        rows = rows - 1
        column = columns

    return (list2)
# Checks for valid user Input
# If letters keeps asking until a number is input
def validChoice(number):

    number = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")

    try :
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        number = validChoice(number)

    return (number)

main()
```

Comment: Are you having a specific problem or error? Otherwise, if you're just looking for feedback on your (working) code you should ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: If the command line is too fast you can add an `input()` or a `time.sleep(0.1)`.

Comment: I wanted to know how I can display the game in 1 board instead of printing out a new board for each iteration they will print out to the same board.